# "The selected directory is not a valid home for IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK" - Windows/IntelliJ/Android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk

i'm trying to add the add the Android SDK to an existing project by --> Project Structure --> Plattform Settings --> SDKs. When choosing the path via dialogue i get, however, the message "The selected directory is not a valid home for IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK".
What did i try so far was:

- run in Administrator mode
- reboot PC
- setting enviroment variable (in systems) for ANDROID_SDK_HOME

I'm aware that i took the path of folder containing the subfolders like platforms, sources etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get this dialog window:

[image]

Select "Android SDK" not "IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK"

Comment: hey, thank you for your respond. i actually don't get the title. i'm just having the first and second option.

Comment: Then you need to install android plugin.

Comment: That's right. It was installed, but not activated. Thank you very much!